# React native dynamic horizontal grid with different item sizes

Tags: react-native

[image]

I want to create horizontal flat list with different item size , suppose i get images from response i want flat list to be display in grid. and if i get video i dont want grid it will display as show in image and list should be horizontally scrollable. please help me if anybody done something like this or anybody know how to do this. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-native-easy-grid. If you check-out github repo its easy to implement such a design. i think such a code can help you

```
<Grid>
  <Col>
    <Row>
      <Text>1</Text>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Text>2</Text>
    </Row>
  </Col>
  <Col>
    <Row>
      <Text>3</Text>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Text>4</Text>
    </Row>
  </Col>
  <Col>
    <Text>5</Text>
  </Col>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I want ui should be dynamic so that any thing come from response it will automatically attach to ui which i show in image , i use that grid library but it dosen't give me proper solution

Comment: but you can use grid library dynamically. you should render dynamcially when you data load.                                                      _dynamicRender(item) {
    return x_data.map((item) => {
      return (
        <Row>...</Row>
      );
    });
  }
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.userTypesContainer}>
            {
              this._dynamicRender(data)
            }
          
      </View>
    )
  }